# Delete sms from sms inbox programatically in android kitkat

Tags: sms, android-4.4-kitkat

Can any one will help me how to delete sms from sms inbox programatically in android kitkat.
Please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20161904/3611813