# Delete SMS on sent folder with python on Android

Tags: android, python, sl4a

i've read [this](https://h3manth.com/content/programmatically-delete-sms-android-using-python) and [this](http://taskerfans.blogspot.it/2013/04/sl4a-python-script-to-manage-android.html) in order to make this script

```
import sl4a

droid = sl4a.Android()

msgs = droid.smsGetMessageIds(False, 'sent')[1]
msgs.extend(droid.smsGetMessageIds(False,'sent')[1])

print(droid.smsGetMessageById(msgs[0], ['address','body','status','error_code']).result)
droid.smsDeleteMessage(msgs[0])
```

My purpose is delete last sms sent. But it does not works. That [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158998/marking-sms-messages-as-read-unread-or-deleting-messages-not-working-in-kitkat) does not work for me. Even if is not my default sms client i can send sms, but i can't delete these sms after sending. What is the problem?

Comment: If you're running on API 4.4 (KitKat) or above, your app has to be the default SMS app to be able to delete messages, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158998/marking-sms-messages-as-read-unread-or-deleting-messages-not-working-in-kitkat).

Comment: That answer does not work for me. Even if is not my default sms client i can send sms, but i can't delete these sms after sending

Comment: Your app doesn't have to be the default app just to send messages. It just can't delete them if it's not the default, because it doesn't have write access to the Provider. Any app can still send messages.

Comment: So there is no way with a python script, right?

Comment: I really doubt it, though I'm not at all familiar with sl4a. Even if you could, though, I doubt the user would want to temporarily switch their default app just to run your script.